# MVC grid table dropdown selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How to set selected value dropdown? The following do not set any selected value.

```
 @for (int i=0; i< Model.Students.Count;i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Students[i].Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.Students[i].Name)
                         </td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Students[i].Age, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>

                        <td>
                            @*@Html.DropDownList("country", Model.Countries,)*@

                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Students[i].Country, Model.Countries)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

ActionResult:

```
  public ActionResult ShowServerSideGrid()
    {
        var list = new List<SelectListItem>
       {
           new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "USA" },
           new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "UK" },
           new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "China" },
           new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "Russia" }
       };
        var students = new List<StudentModel>();
        students.Add(new StudentModel { Country = 1,Age = 24,Name = "Arjun"});
        students.Add(new StudentModel { Country = 2, Age = 24, Name = "Kumar" });
        students.Add(new StudentModel { Country = 3, Age = 45, Name = "Shiva" });
        students.Add(new StudentModel { Country = 4, Age = 60, Name = "Aryal" });
        StudentListModel listModel=new StudentListModel();
        listModel.Students = students;
        listModel.Countries = list;
        return View(listModel);
    }
```

Comment: look at the model being passed to the view.  you are tying your drop down list for to  Model.Students[i].Country.  make sure that that field is set to a value that matches a value in Model.Countries

Comment: If check the actionresult the value Country is set to match the values in selectlistitem

Comment: it may have to do with the foreach.  try putting a drop down list for outside of the foreach to see if it is set.  Also try setting the selected property of one of the select list item to see if the drop downs change from that

Comment: I tried outside loop but doesn't set:  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Students[2].Country, Model.Countries)

Comment: try setting the selected in your List<SelectListItem>

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you resolved it somehow in mean time ?

Answer (score 2):

Please use following code to solve it

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Students[i].Country, new SelectList(Model.Countries,"Value","Text",Model.Students[i].Country))
```

Comment: selectedValue should be supplied when creating SelectList in the loop. So this should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `List<SelectListItem> dropDownValues {get;set;}` in your model

Fill the dropDownValues feild with values in controller

Eg.

```
StudentListModel listModel=new StudentListModel();
listModel.dropDownValues .Add(new SelectListItem{Text = "USA", Value = "1"})
```

....... So on

and in your view you must use the syntax

```
@Html.DropDownFor(x => Model.Students[i].Country, Model.dropDownValues)
```